# Did LinkedIn use PhoneGap or Trigger.IO for its iPhone app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, backbone.js, linkedin-api, trigger.io

I keep reading all these articles how LinkedIn used node.js and backbone.js to build their mobile application.

See this article: http://venturebeat.com/2011/08/16/linkedin-node/

In it they say LinkedIn used only 5% native phone features. The other 95% was cross-platform HTML, JS, and CSS.

What I don't see in the article is any mention of PhoneGap or trigger.io.

So how was linkedin able to make their mobile application with just javascript and access "5%" of the native api's?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually they used websockets to communicate from the JavaScript to native layer.

http://engineering.linkedin.com/mobile/linkedin-ipad-nativeweb-messaging-bridge-and-websockets